VS Code + React + Typescript kills npm run start on nearly any react ENOENT in node_modules/.cache/default-development or SCSS update in files
Nearly any kind of update to a file causes a Kill of the npm run start React processes.

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
/Users/me/Documents/ReactT/App/node_modules/.cache/default-development/1.pack'] {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'stat',
path: '/Users/me/Documents/React/App/node_modules/.cache/default-development/1.pack'
}   `

The only difference in the errors is the final filename. Sometimes it's 2.pack or 1.pack or 8.pack or occasionally something else.

I have tried different SASS extenstions and turning them off.
I have tried adding NODE_ENV variables.
I have to tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling from package.js9n npm i
I have tried finding an answer on the Internet and on SO


try to remove node_modules and reinstall

Sorry I meant to mention that I already did that too @YuMiao
